# Why does CMake's WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS not support exporting static data symbols?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

The [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html) very specifically states this limitation but I can't seem to find any explanation as to why it would be the case.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/export-exports-a-function?view=vs-2019 suggests that this is simply a difference in the syntax MSVC expects wrt importing data vs functions and CMake does in fact export all symbols

Answer (score 1):

I had hoped that CMake's WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS would eliminate the need to alter source code written for GCC to be linked correctly in MSVC.

So with that assumption, I misinterpreted the documentation cited above where it says:

> For global *data* symbols, `__declspec(dllimport)` must still be used when compiling against the code in the `.dll`

and took it as a limitation of the CMake feature, rather than a requirement of MSVC (which was quite my mistake.)

Comment: Mind trying the following: Use Ninja generator and set CMAKE_NM to an installed llvm-nm.exe (<LLVMROOT>/LLVM/bin probably needs to be on PATH for that to work correctly).